# Simple explanation as to why this code wouldn't work

Tags: reactjs

Started to get into react as a part of my BA thessis, need some code as examples but don't want them to be generic, so if someone could please explain as to why this wouldn't work it would be very helpfull, thanks!

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

function Greetings(props){
    return <h1> hello!  {props.name}</h1>;
}

const element = <Greetings name ='Sarah' />;
document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = element.props(name);
```

Comment: This is some very odd code, so i'm not sure what sort of answer you're looking for. The immediate reason it doesn't work is that `element.props` is not a function, and `name` is not defined. More fundamentally though, this is just not the way that elements are intended to be used.

Comment: i was trying to modify a piece of code i found as an example for a component in react.. lets say if instead of `element.props(name)` i wrote just `element` and defined the name with const, would that work?

Comment: `would that work?` What is your goal? What do you want to be assigned to the innerHTML of `'root'`?

Comment: I want the component to display  "Greetings Sarah" in the browser, sorry i didn't specify it before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`element` is a small object describing what you want to be on the page. Basically, it looks like this:

```
const element = {
  type: Greetings,
  props: { name: 'Sarah' }
}
```

This is not something you are intended to use directly. There is no direct way to figure out that Greetings will contain an `<h1>`, or that it will be constructing a string `"hello! Sarah"`. The way to put this element on the page is for react to render it. React will recursively walk down the tree of elements, rendering as needed, and then it will compare what changed and update the DOM.

In react 18, this is done as follows:

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
const element = <Greetings name ='Sarah' />;
root.render(element)
```

`root.render` is typically called exactly once in your app, and from then on you set state to cause rerenders.

Comment: Okay,  your explanation actually helped me to understand the process, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

function Greetings(props){
    return <h1> hello!  {props.name}</h1>;
}

const element = <Greetings name ='Sarah' />;
ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById('root'));
```

https://www.pragimtech.com/blog/reactjs/introduction-to-react-elements/
This may help you.

Comment: Be sure to check it out, thank you very much for your help!